# custom file types in jar

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am developing a Java project in Netbeans which contains multiple files with custom types (like .rml .mod and ...)

The netbeans does not show these files in project, and when I build the project I need to copy them manually so the project can load them.

Is it possible to automatically include these files into output Jar file in build time?

If yes, then how and how can I access them in code?
If no, then how can I manage these files (automatically copy them to desired place and etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a package inside java application and add files to this package.

for access to this files use of following code:

```
getClass().getResource("/Images/imgedit.png")
```

Package name instead of "Images" and file name instead of "imgeit.png".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ant` for building the project

You can take basic reference from [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html)  and [here](http://www.javabeat.net/2008/07/writing-simple-ant-build-script/).

Answer (score 0):

If your data files are in the source folder they should be copied automatically to the bin folder along with the generated class files.
To read a data file from within a jar you could use `getResourceAsStream(String)` available in `Class` class.